# How does Debian differ from Debian-Slim?

Tags: docker, debian, containers

I am trying to select a recommended base Linux distribution for my company's container images.

I have narrowed it down to Debian and Debian-Slim.

Everything I read says that Debian-Slim is just a pared down distribution.  But I can't seem to find hard details on how they differ.

What capabilities are in Debian that are not in Debian-Slim?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can compare the [git repos used to build the images](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/tree/7a782c4f5f3a161936db0cd26a2623b4017d797c/stable) (rootfs.manifest is useful). Or you can run each image and see what they show is different:

```
$ docker run --rm debian:stable dpkg --get-selections >debian-stable-pkgs.txt

$ docker run --rm debian:stable-slim dpkg --get-selections >debian-stable-slim-pkgs.txt

$ diff debian-stable-pkgs.txt debian-stable-slim-pkgs.txt
23,24d22
< iproute2                                      install
< iputils-ping                                  install
35,36d32
< libcap2:amd64                                 install
< libcap2-bin                                   install
40d35
< libelf1:amd64                                 install
53d47
< libmnl0:amd64                                 install
77d70
< libxtables12:amd64                            install
```

Additionally, as [Tomofumi points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794891/how-does-debian-differ-from-debian-slim/59795153#comment107895104_59795153), there are various [files excluded](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype/blob/master/scripts/.slimify-excludes) from the image (with some others [reincluded](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype/blob/master/scripts/.slimify-includes)). These are mostly documentation and language support:

```
/usr/share/doc/*
/usr/share/info/*
/usr/share/linda/*
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/*
/usr/share/locale/*
/usr/share/man/*
/usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/*/*
/usr/share/gnome/help/*/*
/usr/share/locale/*
/usr/share/omf/*/*-*.emf
```

So by excluding a handful of packages, and stripping various docs and localization files, they were able to trim 45MB from the image, or about 40%.

```
$ docker image ls debian
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
debian              stable-slim         eb8569e750e6        2 weeks ago         69.2MB
debian              stable              405289501bdf        2 weeks ago         114MB
```

Comment: Huh.  So those seven module are all that is missing from Debian-Slim.  Add them back in and you have Debian again?  If so, that clears it up quite well for me.

Comment: There are more files will be removed during the build script debuerreotype-slimify, the list of removed files is here: https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype/blob/master/scripts/.slimify-excludes

Comment: good answer, but not accurate anymore. I just checked it and installed packages are exactly the same now. It seems that the only difference is now within /usr/share/. See https://serverfault.com/questions/1013369/what-is-the-difference-between-debian-slim-buster-and-buster-images